# Roots of $x^{30}-1$ in a finite polynomial quotent field.

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

Let $F=\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} [x]$ (polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$) and $I=(x^2 + \overline{2})$ be the ideal generated by $x^2 + \overline{2}$ . Consider the quotent field $F/I$. Find the elements $u \in F/I$ such that $u^{30} =1$. This is equivalent to finding the roots of $x^{30} -1$ in this strange field.

As the element $u\in F/I$ has the form $u=[\overline{a}x+\overline{b}]$ I have tried expanding $u^{30}$ using the binomial formula, then use the fact that $[x^2]=[\overline{-2}]$ to reduce the candidates and finally just use try and error.

Is there a more "elegant" way to solve this question? (With "elegant" I mean not doing so many computations).

I hope that the notation is clear.

Comment: Anyway, you have a field $F/I$. It has characteristic five, so we have the factorization
$$x^{30}-1=(x^6)^5-1^5=(x^6-1)^5.$$ Try and find the zeros of $x^6-1$ instead. There are six of those in this field, each a root of multiplicity five.

Comment: There are many ways to find those zeros. One is that the multiplicative group of $F/I$ is cyclic of order $24$. This implies that *anything (non-zero) raised to fourth power is a zero*.

Comment: Yet another way is that you may remember from having seen complex sixth (and third) roots of unity written in terms of $\sqrt{-3}$. Here is your lucky break. In your field $-3=-(-2)=4(-2)$, so given that you just adjoined $\sqrt{-2}$, you can use $2\sqrt{-2}=\sqrt{-3}$ interchangeably.

Comment: Please don't ask me to post any or all of the above as an answer. I will gladly explain this many times over, but I have already explained all those tricks in many other threads (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2317055/11619)), and I firmly think that duplicating that amounts to adding noise to the site (opinions differ there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, as $5=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}[x]$, we have that $(a+b)^5=a^5+b^5$ for all $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}[x] $, so we get that 
$$x^{30}-1=(x^6-1)^5=((x^3-1)(x^3+1))^5=((x-1)(x+1)(x^2-x+1)(x^2+x+1))^5$$
already in $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}[x]$, hence in the field $K:=F/I$, which contain $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$.

Hence you only need to find the roots of each polynomial: they are $u=\pm 1$ plus the roots of $x^2\pm x+1$. A simple computation shows that 
$(\pm \bar x + 2)^2=2\mp \bar x -1$, hence $\pm \bar x+2$ is a root of $y^2+y+1$. Similarly for $(\pm \bar x + 3)$ and $y^2-y+1$. Hence the answer is $$\{\pm 1,\pm \bar x + 3,\pm \bar x + 2\}$$

Comment: thanks, I corrected

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
x^{30}-1=(x^2 + 4x + 1)^5(x^2 + x + 1)^5(x + 4)^5(x + 1)^5
$$
in $\Bbb F_5[x]$ by Jyrki's comment. Now we can consider this modulo $I=(x^2+2)$.

Comment: With the factorization in place the OP is now well placed to find the zeros using the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 1):

$K=F/I$ is a field with $25$ elements. Therefore, its multiplicative group $K^\times$ is cyclic of order $24$. Finally, $u^{30}=1$ iff $u^6=u^{\gcd(30,24)}=1$. Since $K^\times$ is cyclic, it all reduces to finding a generator $g$ and taking the subgroup generated by $g^4$.

Comment: This works, but you can also just take fourth powers of random elements.

Comment: Could you explain why $u^{30}=1$ iff $u^6 = u^{gcd(30,24)}=1$ ?

Comment: @Andarrkor, $6 = 30 - 24$.